# ¿Porque mi párrafo se sale de los limites de un elemento?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Tengo la mayor parte del código resuelto, pero no puedo con un simple problema, y es que los párrafos que son creados luego con una función llamada por sockets, si son demasiado largos, en vez de tener el comportamiento normal (y bajar una linea si no caben), no lo hacen!, simplemente siguen derecho y traspasan todos los elementos que estan fuera de el...

No entiendo por que pasa y ya me ha pasado en otros proyectos... ojala puedan ayudarme a solucionarlo...

Ya intente colocarle un height al contenedor que contiene a los parrafos (pero no funcionó), intente establecer display block a todos los elementos

, pero tampoco funcionó, le intente establecer un display block al elemento padre pero tampoco funcionó...

este es el codigo:

//HTML



    
    Web sockets

```
<div class="chat" id = "chat">

    <h1 class = "titulo">Web sockets!</h1>
    <div class="espacioMensajes" id = "espacioMensajes">

        <div class="mensajes" id = "mensajes"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="contenedorCampos">

        <input type="text" placeholder="nombre" id = "nombre" class = "campos"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="escriba el mensaje aquí" id = "mensaje" class = "campos"/>

        <input type = "button" class = "enviarMensaje" id = "enviarMensaje" value = "enviar"/>

    </div>

</div>
```

//JS
window.onload = ()=>{

```
let socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8080/");
let msgs;

let espacioMensajes = document.getElementById("espacioMensajes");
let output = document.getElementById("mensajes"); 
let nombre = document.getElementById("nombre");
let mensaje = document.getElementById("mensaje");
let enviar = document.getElementById("enviarMensaje");

enviar.addEventListener("click", ()=>{

    socket.emit("sendMsg",{

        nombre:nombre.value,
        mensaje:mensaje.value

    });

});



socket.on("sendMsg",data =>{

    if(data.mensaje.trim() != "" && data.nombre.trim() != "" && (output.offsetHeight < espacioMensajes.offsetHeight)){

        output.innerHTML += "<p><strong>" + data.nombre + ":</strong>" + data.mensaje + "</p>";
        mensaje.focus();

    }else{

        if(data.mensaje.trim() != "" && data.nombre.trim() != ""){

            msgs = document.getElementsByClassName("parrafo");

            for(let i = msgs.length-1; i >= 0; i--){

                output.removeChild(msgs[i]);

            }

        }


    }

});
```

}

//CSS

```
*{

    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

body{

    background-color:#E1E0E1;

}

.titulo{

    text-align: center;

}

.chat{

    background-color:#ffffff;
    margin:auto;
    display:block;
    width: 40%;
    height: 750px;
    padding: 30px;

}

.espacioMensajes{

    height: 450px;
    width: 100%;
    border:2px solid #AAAAAA;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin:auto;

}

.campos{
    display:block;
    transition: 1s ease;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding:5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    border:2px solid #bbbbbb;

}

.campos:hover{
    transition: 1s ease;
    border:2px solid #40BFDB;

}

.mensajes{

    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: "Lucida Console";
    font-size:15px;
    display: block;

}

.contenedorCampos{

    width:100%;
    height: 80px;

}

.enviarMensaje{
    margin: auto;
    transition: 1s ease;
    padding:20px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: "Lucida Console";
    background-color:#000000;
    color:#ffffff;
    display:block;
    margin-top: 20px;

}

.enviarMensaje:hover{

    transition: 1s ease;
    background-color:red;
    cursor:pointer;

}


@media screen and (max-width: 1000px){

    .chat{

        width:60%;

    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px){

    .chat{

        width:100%;

    }

}
```

Comment: prueba agregandole este css al elemento html que lo contiene al párrafo por ejemplo `word-break: break-word;`

Comment: Me ha funcionado!, perfecto!, así que esa es la propiedad que hace que los párrafos se comporten así... ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: vale, no te preocupes ;3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ocupa la propiedad en CSS que se llama `break-word` que romperá una cadena de texto en múltiples renglones para que no rebasen el ancho de su contenedor principal, su sintaxis es así

`word-break: break-word;`

Entonces a tu contenedor padre que tiene al texto le puedes aplicar es propiedad así

```
p{
      word-break: break-word;
    }
```

Mira este ejemplo mostrando el texto desbordado

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
      <style>
        p{
          background-color: red;
          width: 300px;
          
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>
      By myself lonk lonk lonk lonk the crimation crimationcrimationcrimationcrimationcrimationcrimationcrimationcrimationcrimationrmation.
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Ahora mira el mismo ejemplo funcional con la propiedad aplicada para evitar el desbordamiento

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    p{
      background-color: red;
      width: 300px;
      word-break: break-word;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>
  By myself lonk lonk lonk lonk the crimation crimationcrimationcrimationcrimationcrimationcrimationcrimationcrimationcrimationrmation.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ya valide la respuesta, excelente trabajo con el ejemplo y todo, gracias por tomarte ese tiempo!, espero que te hayan llegado los puntos ;3

Comment: si, un gusto apoyarte @Riven saludos